# Nuget 'Could not find a part of the path' error on self-hosted Bitbucket Windows runner

Tags: .net, windows, nuget, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to create a Bitbucket pipeline running on self-hosted Windows Runner for a .NET Framework project.
So this is how my `bitbucket-pipeline.yml` file looks like:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        runs-on:
          - "windows"
        script:
          - nuget.exe restore .\MyProject.sln -source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json;http://nuget.mycompany.com/nuget"
          - msbuild .\MyProject.sln
```

But I get this error on pipeline:

```
...
...
...
Adding package 'System.ValueTuple.4.5.0' to folder 'C:\Windows\system32\atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner\temp\200c6e7a-b2bb-52a1-93a4-59b520d83266\1682613154669\build\packages'
Restoring NuGet package WebGrease.1.6.0.
Adding package 'WebGrease.1.6.0' to folder 'C:\Windows\system32\atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner\temp\200c6e7a-b2bb-52a1-93a4-59b520d83266\1682613154669\build\packages'


Errors in packages.config projects
    Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner\temp\200c6e7a-b2bb-52a1-93a4-59b520d83266\1682613154669\build\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.11.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.targets'.
    Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system32\atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner\temp\200c6e7a-b2bb-52a1-93a4-59b520d83266\1682613154669\build\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.11.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.targets'.

NuGet Config files used:
    C:\Windows\system32\atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner\temp\200c6e7a-b2bb-52a1-93a4-59b520d83266\1682613154669\build\NuGet.Config
    C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config
    C:\Program Files (x86)\NuGet\Config\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config

Feeds used:
    C:\Users\myPc\.nuget\packages\
    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
    http://nuget.mycompany.com/nuget

Installed:
    33 package(s) to packages.config projects
```

What Should I do ? How can I handle that error ?

Comment: I noticed that at the beginning of the pipeline there is an error: `C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\zibzxppb.oca.nugetrestore.targets(399,5): error MSB3202: The project file "C:\Windows\system32\atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner\temp\200c6e7a-b2bb-52a1-93a4-59b520d83266\1682613154669\build\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" was not found. [C:\Users\myPc\AppData\Local\Temp\NuGetScratch\xvsnoudf.15o.nugetinputs.targets]`

Comment: "could not find part of path" is Windows' weird error message meaning "path too long" (exceeds the ~250 MAX_PATH limit). So, assuming it's a version of Windows that supports long path, try turning on long path in the registry

Answer (score 1):

There is 250 character Max path limit in related Windows version. All I had to do is to reduce character size of the path. (Thanks to @zivkan). If you have some dependencies with long names, you can just rename the folder names.

What I did is to change `"atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner"` to `"runner"` which makes absolute path shorter. You can simply change it to `"a"` :D

Comment: The 250 character limit clobbered my build, too. Putting the runner in a directory with a shorter name (ex. C:\runners\<project>\) solve the issue for me. Thanks for sharing the answer.